# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'compilerOptions'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to update my Angular4 application to Angular5.

I tryed to follow the procedure suggested by the official site but now I can't no more compile and I get this error:

**error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'compilerOptions'.**

This is the version of the components:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 7.4.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.7.1
webpack: 3.10.0
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "jqueryui",
      "jasmine",
      "datatables.net",
      "datatables.net-select"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "types" : [ "node" ]
 }

  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks to support

Comment: Could you post the content of `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Sure, I intregrate it in the question

Comment: @DarioN1 check my posted format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an error in your tsconfig.json format which is mentioned in the error message. You have one extra `compilerOptions` property inside the original `compilerOptions` object. it should be like below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "jqueryui",
      "jasmine",
      "datatables.net",
      "datatables.net-select"
    ]

  }
}
```

However `typeRoots` will be given preference instead of `types` here and all packages will be loaded from `"../node_modules/@types"`. Check this link for all the options .

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html